# How can we pass in an ExpectedConditions as a parameter to wait.until in Selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm finding trouble passing in an `ExpectedConditions` as a parameter in a method to `wait.until()`. The `wait.until()` expects a function to be passed in. I am relatively new to Java, and would appreciate the assistance.

Offending code:

```
public void waitUntil(WebElement element, long seconds, String errorMessage, ExpectedConditions expectedConditions) {
 if (seconds == 0 || errorMessage.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(seconds));
 wait.withMessage(errorMessage);
 // this throws a compiler error.
 wait.until(expectedConditions);
}
```

`wait.until()` expects a function to be passed into it, which looks like `ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("http://www.test.com")`.

I am trying to make a method that could be called where any ExpectedCondition i.e. urlToBe, alertIsPresent etc.. could be passed in.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the compiler error says?

Comment: ```Required type: Function <? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver, V>
Provided: ExpectedConditions

reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that ExpectedConditions conforms to Function<? super WebDriver, V>```

Comment: What if you change the 4th parameter to: `ExpectedCondition<?> expectedConditions`?

Comment: What type should the <?> be?

Comment: Just leave it as `?` . It is called wildcards: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: I see, the compiler error has gone. Testing it now, will report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(WebElement element, long seconds, String errorMessage, ExpectedConditions expectedConditions)
```

In first place, the type of `expectedConditions` is wrong.

You declared it as `ExpectedConditions`, which represents the util class.

You actually want `ExpectedCondition`, the type which all methods from `ExpectedConditions` returns.

But just changing it to `ExpectedCondition` is not enough. Because you will receive an warning about `Raw type`, because `ExpectedCondition` is a generic class.

So you have to declare the type parameter of class, and because you want to include everything, you use wildcard `?`

In the final, the parameter should be `ExpectedCondition<?> expectedConditions`

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverWait has a constructor that is overloaded to take long as a second args. You do not need to use `Duration.ofSeconds(seconds)`

Also,

```
The method until(Function<? super WebDriver,V>) in the type FluentWait<WebDriver> is not applicable for the arguments (ExpectedConditions)
```

Fix :

You should use expectedConditions with one the conjunction like

1. elementToBeClickable
2. visibilityOfElement

and so on..

**Code :**

```
public void waitUntil(WebElement element, long seconds, String errorMessage, ExpectedConditions expectedConditions) {
     if (seconds == 0 || errorMessage.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
     wait.withMessage(errorMessage);
     WebElement elemenet  = wait.until(expectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//some xpath")));
    }
```

**Internal overloaded method :**

```
  */
  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds) {
    this(
        driver,
        java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone(),
        Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER,
        timeOutInSeconds,
        DEFAULT_SLEEP_TIMEOUT);
  }
```

Comment: The thing is, using ```long``` or ```int``` only is now deprecated, it has the @Deprecated annotation on it. Selenium authors want us to use the ```Duration.ofSeconds()``` as an argument.

Comment: @SilentKay : Which version you are on ?

Comment: Selenium 4.0.0.

Just to add -> i'm aware you can use ```ExpectedConditions.urlToBe(url)``` and just pass the ```url``` into it. But that means i'll have to create a separate method for each condition. Whereas, I would rather prefer it to be generic, so I can pass in an ExpectedCondition object into the method, with any condition as the caller sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anythin wrong in your code block. However you need to ensure a couple of things as follows:

- Whhile using *ExpectedConditions* you have to make the following import:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  ```
- As you are using *Selenium 4.0.0* you need to use *`guava-31.0.1-jre.jar`*

Comment: Yes, I removed it for brevity reasons. But it is already there.

Comment: Cross check the guava version.

Comment: I'm not sure what "guava" has to do with passing a static method into a method to be called upon?

Comment: Seems you got a working and an Accepted answer. So I'll skip the explanation. Good Luck